# Excel grade formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am currently doing a formula to find the overall grade for a student that has done 2 exams and 1 assignment.

I have made a formula that can achieve the task, but i have ran into a problem and I dont exactly understand why its giving me the incorrect answer.

As you can see in the screen shot provided you can see the 2 exams and 1 assignment, the grades are, A, A+, B+ which averaged should come out to a a value of 13.66 and as a grade as A (rounded upwards) but when i click out of the cell it shows a C+ and I dont understand why.

```
=INDEX(L$2:L$16,MATCH(SUMPRODUCT((E8:G8=L$2:L$16)*(M$2:M$16))/COUNTA(E8:G8), M$2:M$16,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: In the "Formulas" menu, there's "Formula auditing", which contains "Evaluate Formula". This feature performs formula calculation step by step, you can follow this and see at which step things are going wrong.

Comment: i have tried that and unfortunately i dont understand what it says (just repeats false and i click evaluate and just some how randomly gets to C+)

Comment: I've tested this, and for Row 5 (Student 4) it calculates as though cell `G5` has a Space in it instead of being Blank (i.e. `COUNTA(E5:G5)` is 3 instead of 2).  Also, have you checked if Calculation is Automatic or Manual (e.g. does pressing "F9" fix the sheet?)

Comment: i am aware (i think) of this issue, and the value of a blank (i think once again) is 2 (2 points)

Comment: but i have checked it and checked with my teacher and he said that that should be the correct grade that he would have given, so currently the only issue is with that cell (there are more cells with that issue but i think i can manage to fix them if i get the appropriate help)

Comment: If you take A, A+ & B+ then put a space after the A like A<space> then the A is not given a value since it fails lookup but it is still counted, hence C+ average.

Comment: @Jeeped i am dumb, i am so dumb, it was due to the spacing, idk i i didnt think of that, oml, btw thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution since you specified that its only for three scores, is to use the average of three separate lookups, something like:

`=AVERAGE(VLOOKUP(E6,gradevalues,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F6,gradevalues,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G6,gradevalues,2,FALSE))`

...where `gradevalues` is a named range representing the list of lettergrades-to-scores.

eg.,

[image: img]

Comment: humm, but see, the problem in that formula is that if there is a missing identity in the boxes it will say N/A, but in my case it can calculate the average of three grades in lettergrades and also if there is a missing box it will make sure to still give a appropriate grade

Comment: also i have inserted your formula and in majority of the overall grades it just came back with N/A

Comment: @BAZAMEEE You can either use an average of  `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(..),0)` to make un-assigned grades 0, or replace `AVERAGE(<List>)` with `AGGREGATE(1,6,<List>)` to `AVERAGE` all non-error values, etc

Comment: humm, that still dosnt take the fact it dosent work for almost 1/6 of the 100 students, but i appreciate your effort, also i would prefer if you could improve my formula to make it not mis calculate. Thanks

Comment: @BAZAMEEE you should trst for all three values being present and correct, then apply the answer given.

Comment: i have done that and the values are correct to i converted them to the letter grade and something went wring midway and i dont know what.

Comment: thank you guys but the problem was with the spacing... so yea just proves im dumb lol, but thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Your original formula is exactly right.

After hand typing everything in from your example, it works flawlessly.

Comment: yea i reilaised my flaws, i didnt put a space